# Return maximum ID number from a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vb.net, iteration

This is probably an easy thing to do, but I'm only doing my first vb project so I'm not sure how to do this 100%, so apologies in advanced if the following problem is actually very simple.

Basically, what I need to do is, when loading a database table into an ultragrid, I need to retrieve the maximum integer that is stored in a field.

To explain this more clearly, each record in the database has it's own ID number, so I need to iterate each record and find the one with the highest ID number, and return the ID, so that this can then be used in other calculations.

I know that I can use `SQL = SELECT MAX(supportID) FROM tblIncidents` for example to retrieve the highest ID number stored in this table.

So, how do I go about declaring the result of this (so, the highest ID number) as variable so that I can firstly display it in a messagebox to prove to me that the query has worked, and secondly so that I can use the variable as means of using the ID throughout my code?

An example; This is the code to save a new record into the tblIncidents table.

```
 Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    Dim incidentSolved As Boolean = False
    If cboxSolved.Checked Then
        incidentSolved = True
    End If

    If txtClientSave.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Client name cannot be blank")

    ElseIf rtbProblem.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Problem cannot be blank")

    ElseIf cboxSolved.Checked = True And rtbSolution.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter solution")

    Else
        database.SaveNewIncident(txtClientSave.Text, dtpStart.Value, dtpEnd.Value, rtbProblem.Text, dtpStartTime.Value, dtpEndTime.Value, cboxSolved.Checked, rtbSolution.Text, _con)

        txtClientSave.Text = ""
        rtbProblem.Text = ""
        rtbSolution.Text = ""
        dtpStart.Value = Date.Today
        dtpEnd.Value = Date.Today
        dtpStartTime.Value = DateTime.Now
        dtpEndTime.Value = DateTime.Now
        cboxSolved.Checked = False

    End If
End Sub
```

Database function that is called

```
Public Shared Function SaveNewIncident(ByVal clientName As String, dateStart As Date, dateEnd As Date, ByVal incidentProblem As String, ByVal timeStart As String, ByVal timeEnd As String,
                                       ByVal incidentSolved As Boolean, ByVal incidentSolution As String, _Con As OleDbConnection)

    Dim tr As OleDbTransaction = Nothing

    Try
        tr = _Con.BeginTransaction()

        Dim Dc As New OleDbCommand
        Dc.Connection = _Con

        Dc.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Dc.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.tblIncidents VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
        Dc.Transaction = tr
        Dc.Parameters.Add("@clientName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = clientName
        Dc.Parameters.Add("@dateStart", OleDbType.Date).Value = dateStart
        Dc.Parameters.Add("@dateEnd", OleDbType.Date).Value = dateEnd
        Dc.Parameters.Add("@incidentProblem", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = incidentProblem
        Dc.Parameters.Add("@timeStart", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = timeStart
        Dc.Parameters.Add("@timeEnd", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = timeEnd
        Dc.Parameters.Add("@incidentSolved", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = incidentSolved
        Dc.Parameters.Add("@incidentSolution", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = incidentSolution

        Dc.ExecuteNonQuery()

        tr.Commit()

        MsgBox("Save successful")

    Catch ex As Exception

        mdInit.errorLog(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace)
        MsgBox("Failed to save data, refer to error log")
        tr.Rollback()

    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, this type of logic is often not a good approach because what happens if once you retrieve that value a new one is inserted by somebody else?

Comment: @SeanLange Hi Sean, this application is only going to be used by 1 person, so the insertion confusion won't happen. The reason I need to do this, is because I wrote an import feature to the program to overwrite an existing database with a new one, however that meant turning off Identity_Insert in SQL Server. So now on my save button, I need to retrieve the highest current ID and increment it to determine the value going into the ID column

Comment: Why not insert the row and use the OUTPUT clause? That way you don't have to hope that your value is the same.

Comment: @SeanLange As for what I have tried, I just wanted to return the highest ID in a MsgBox for now, just to show the code in the question worked. I declared sql as an OleDbCommand and the below the code I included I did `MsgBox(sql)` however this didn't work, as it said that the object reference was not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @SeanLange What do you mean by use the OUTPUT clause? Will this allow me solve the problem more easily?

Comment: You can read about the OUTPUT clause here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Comment: We could probably help you fix what you have but you haven't actually posted any code yet.

Comment: @SeanLange Okay, I've added some code that is used to enter records into one particular table. However, I need to add a way of inserting a new ID (so, current maxID + 1), into the supportID field

Comment: `Insert and return the new ID in one call`...

Comment: @Zaggler How would I do this? I know I can use `SELECT MAX(ID) FORM tablename` to find the maxiumum, but how would I then insert it and return it?

Answer (score 0):

what you can do in VB.net is define a SQLcommand which will require a SQL connection attached to it - since your query returns a single value you will be able to execute it with ExecuteScalar to return a single value eg

```
Dim cmd AS New SqlClient.SQLCommand("SELECT MAX(billID) FROM tblRecurring",connectionString)
```

then

```
cmd.connection.open
```

and then

```
dim x as MaxId = cmd.executeScalar
```

and finish off with

```
cmd.connection.dispose
```

of course

Comment: Hi Andrew, the line 'Dim x As MaxID` doesn't work as maxID is not being declared?